# Download every npm dependency, all 60,095 of them

Tags: node.js, npm

I just got my hands on some new hardware at work which means I have 6,000TB at my disposal, I'm working more and more with node.js so thought it would be handy to have every single dependency on npm and then just update them. Thought about it again and keeping them up to date will basically ruin the idea but don't want to believe it so still keen for the [JOURNEY](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=N5wVZwdHmRY).

If anyone knows the special command to take your computer out of action for a few hours/days/weeks let me know! oddly enough I couldn't see it documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole list of packages is available as JSON here https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all (`npm` builds its index from this file).

I suppose you could make a short node.js program that pulls the list and then execs

```
npm install -g <package>
```

for every single one of them .

Comment: worked!ing... tried once but forgot to show progress - because we all know what it's like to `dd` for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to run a private NPM mirror. In which case, check out https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-mirror (and `npm-server`).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the special command would be something like this:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate \
     -d '{"source":"http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/registry/", "target":"registry", "create_target":true}' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```